# Change data in array

Tags: php

I have problem with change data in two+dimension array

Definitions array is ok.

Only problem is, that value ->"class='rd-nav-item active'" not want to save :9

```
$topMenu    = $this->cusData->get_top_menu();

for($i=0;$i<count($topMenu);$i++){
    If($topMenu[$i][1] == $this->link){
        $topMenu[$i][3] = "class='rd-nav-item active'"; 
    }  
}


public function get_top_menu() {
    return Array(
                Array(
                    "Home",
                    "/",
                    "home.php",
                    ""
                )
            );
 }
```

Comment: Did you tried to `var_dump($topMenu)` after the for loop? Did the variables in the array changes? I expected it would, because I can see nothing stopping that part to work. You problem seems to be framework specific. The part you shown is not your problem, but there is not enough to show what your actual problem could be.

Comment: ehhh my mistate, i put the code under include_once :D ehhhh sorry